# Where is it? - The Google Earth Challenge Ep. 3

Tags: visual, geography

Seems got well-reputed for this puzzle series :D, and the next question is ready!
 I wish I could give out the first hint this time... Everyone is really great in PSE!

---

This puzzle will provide a screenshot in somewhere on Google Earth, please try your best to identify where the location is. The reasons to find out the location should be part of your answer.

Will give a zoom-out image as the next hint if not be answered yet for a while.

**Note:** It's not recommended to use Google Search by Image function directly(I'll try my best to avoid that when selecting the screenshot). **Try to use any feature on pixels or your geography knowledge to derive the location.**

---

**Question:**

[image]

Comment: Do we have any guarantee that up is north?

Comment: @boboquack Yes up should be the north, I didn't do any image rotation~

Comment: A good strategy is to look for rivers that flow from west to east (or east to west). From the landscape, it looks like somewhere in East Asia – maybe the Three Gorges Dam?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To me, the first thought that came to mind

> was the Panama Canal

I looked at Google Maps and found

> the same shoreline and ship. See https://www.google.com/maps/place/Panama+Canal/@9.1196581,-79.7389322,960m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x8fab5f4b31cd492d:0xd9dd11e7a14a0960!8m2!3d9.1438034!4d-79.7285161

Not sure what else you need for a solution but will add if necessary

Comment: Great work SteveV~ !